# Getting the contents of Arduino's flash memory back

Tags: embedded, arduino, avr, avrdude, winavr

I have a code burned on Arduino uno and I want to get the hex file of this code back?!

How can I make that ?!

Comment: Get the datasheet for the part it explains how to read and/or write the prom(s)...

Answer (score 0):

On this forum it says you can extract the code from the Arduino to your computer but it will be in executable code which you cannot edit (it would probably be faster to rewrite the program)

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,48218.0.html

Comment: The question only asks about retrieving the content as a hex file, so it seems that is exactly what is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can read-out flash from an AVR via the [ISP](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0943.pdf) (if it has not been disabled) if you have suitable [hardware/software](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/avrdude.html).  You can build the hardware using [another Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP#.UxOpLkt9TWw), use "avrisp" as the ISP interface device ID in avrdude.

Do not disable the power to the AVR's SPI port - this will also disable the ISP interface (same pins), and lock you out permanently if you don't have a working bootloader to load code to re-enable again!